# How to call a spring-boot java application from docker shell script (entrypoint)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a `Dockerfile` that ends with:

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]`

Now I want to run some initialisation from a shell script before that. So I have to refactor that to:

`ENTRYPOINT[ /entrypoint.sh]`

With:

```
!#/bin/bash
echo "some init"

#TODO
#ENTRYOINT["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Question: how can I actually simulate the java entrypoint inside the shell script?

Comment: Not sure i follow the question? you have a command inside ENTRYPOINT which is `java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher`.

In case you want to run a shell script instead, why don't you just add that command to the sheel script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShellScript can be edited to run normal Java file.

From docker documentation:

If you need to write a starter script for a single executable, you can ensure that the final executable receives the Unix signals by using exec

```
!#/bin/bash
echo "some init"

#Execute using linux 'exec' Java launcher
exec java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: if the entrypoint wrapper ends with the line `exec "$@"`, then it will run the image's `CMD`.  If you change the `ENTRYPOINT` you have now to `CMD` then you won't have to hard-code it in the script.

---

In the plain Dockerfile as you have it now, you can change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` with no effect on how you use the container.

```sh
FROM openjdk:17
...
# not ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

On its own, this gives you some flexibility; for example, it's straightforward to peek inside the container, or to launch an interactive shell instead of the normal container process.

```sh
docker run --rm my-image ls /app
docker run --rm -it my-image sh
```

Now, if you have `CMD` this way, you can add an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script to it fairly straightforwardly.  [The `CMD` is passed to the `ENTRYPOINT` as additional arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) and the shell invocation `exec "$@"` will run whatever is passed as the `CMD`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh
echo "some init"
touch /init-has-happened
exec "$@"
```

Importantly, this works with the alternate `docker run` commands I showed above.  The alternate `docker run` command replaces the Dockerfile `CMD` but leaves the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper intact, so the alternate command gets run in the `exec "$@"` line at the end.

```sh
docker run --rm my-image ls -l /init-has-happened
# the file will exist because the entrypoint wrapper creates it
```